# v-for loop only array correspond to the dynamic page number

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I store results per page number, see below:

```
<ul v-for="iten in listingsData" :key="item.id">
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
<button @click="pushPrev">Push Prev Results</button>
<button @click="pushNext">Push Next Results</button>

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            listingsData : [],
            page : 1
        }
    },
    methods : {
        pushNext(){
            var _self = this;
            axios.get('https://myapi.com/get/users?page='+this.page+1).then(function(response){
                _self.page = _self.page + 1;
                _self.listingsData = _self.listingsData.push({
                    page : _self.page,
                    results : response.data.results

                })

            });    
        },
        pushPrev(){
            var _self = this;
            axios.get('https://myapi.com/get/users?page='+this.page-1).then(function(response){
                _self.page = _self.page + 1;
                _self.listingsData = _self.listingsData.push({
                    page : _self.page,
                    results : response.data.results
                })

            });    
        }
    }
    created(){
        //load default data
        var _self = this;
        axios.get('https://myapi.com/get/users?page='+this.page).then(function(response){
            _self.listingsData = {
                page : 1,
                results : response.data.results

            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Now how I can show or loop only results correspond to the the page number `this.page`?

```
_self.listingsData = _self.listingsData.push({
    page : _self.page, // page number
    results : response.data.results
})
```

What can I try?

I'm using Vue CLI and webpack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over computed property that will return specific page from `listingsData`, not over all pages.

Something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="currentPage">
    <ul v-for="item in currentPage.results" :key="item.id">
      <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div v-else><i>Loading...</i></div>

  <button @click="fetchPage(-1)" :disabled="page===1">Prev Results</button>
  <button @click="fetchPage(1)" :disabled="page===10">Next Results</button>
</template>

<script>
const api = "https://myapi.com/get/users";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      page: 1,
      listingsData: [],
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchPage(0);
  },
  computed: {
    currentPage() {
      return this.listingsData.find(i => i.page === this.page);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPage(diff) {
      this.page += diff;
      if (this.currentPage) {
        return; // page already loaded
      }
      const page = this.page;
      axios.get(api, { params: { page } })
           .then((res) => {
             this.listingsData.push({
               page,
               results: res.data.results,
             });
           });
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Here, we're loading page only if it hasn't been loaded before, and disable Prev/Next buttons if current page is 1/10 respectively.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxz8bjwL/) (with mockup data instead of actual API calls).

Comment: thank you, tried your code but seems not working on my end, it gives me 'returns undefined' from this v-for="item in currentPage.results" any ideas, help please?

Comment: i get an error saying, results is undefined, its because, listingsData is empty and currentPage computed property returns empty too.

Comment: That's correct behavior, the "Loading..." should be shown and page content should be loaded.